# drop duplicates and keep first in a csv file in unix

Tags: linux, csv, unix

Hi I have a csv file whose content is like

```
NAME,AGE
abc,12
def,13
NAME,AGE  ##here duplicates :though these are column names
sdd,34
krgj,656
```

I tried a sort command to do that as:

```
sort -u file.csv -o file.csv
```

but all the duplicate rows got dropped(kept the last one ), but i need to keep the first one , so that I can have my column/header safe.

Please help in this regards.

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic awk program for this task is:

```
awk '!seen[$0]++' file
```

For each line ($0) in the file, we increment the number of times we've seen that line. Since we're using the post-increment operator,
the first time a line is encountered, the value of `seen[$0]++` is zero. For all other instances of that line, the value is non-zero. So we negate the value to get a true value for the first time seen. The default action is to print the line.

Comment: Any way to redirect those seen values to a FIle? That will help me a lot.

Comment: Just use regular redirection like you've seen a million times `awk ... file > otherfile`

Comment: Almost same in perl: `perl -ne 'print if not $seen{$_}++' file`. See [-n](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#-n).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the most elegant solution but it works.

`head -n1 source.csv > output.csv; grep -v "$(head -n1 source.csv)" source.csv >> output.csv`

It works by writing `>` the first line to `output.csv` then removing all the first lines using `grep -v` and appending `>>` the result to `output.csv`

Example:

```
root@merlin:/tmp# cat source.csv 
NAME,AGE
abc,12
def,13
NAME,AGE
sdd,34
krgj,656
root@merlin:/tmp# head -n1 source.csv > output.csv; grep -v "$(head -n1 source.csv)" source.csv >> output.csv
root@merlin:/tmp# cat output.csv 
NAME,AGE
abc,12
def,13
sdd,34
krgj,656
```

If you need to dedup it as well:

`head -n1 source.csv > output.csv; grep -v "$(head -n1 source.csv)" source.csv |sort -u >> output.csv`

Answer (score 0):

Using [datamash](http://www.gnu.org/software/datamash)'s non-sorting deduplication line filter "*rmdup*", (requires `datamash` *v1.0.7* or newer):

```
datamash rmdup 1 < source.csv
```

Output:

```
NAME,AGE
abc,12
def,13
sdd,34
krgj,656
```

Comment: @agc-I installed datamash by rpm...and then executed the command as per your answer, but got an error "datamash: invalid operation 'rmdup'". the command was >>> datamash rmdup 1 < test.csv

Comment: @LoneRanger, `rmdup` requires `datamash` *v1.0.7* (from 2015) or newer.   Online I only see *v1.0.6* *rpm*s.   Perhaps I've missed it.  Then there's the option of installing the hard way, using the [upstream source for *v1.1.0*](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/datamash/).